# switching back to text console

Tags: kernel, hardware, console

I have used ubuntu many times but currently ubuntu crashed every time on my system.
I dont understand the exact problem of my computer. I have tried every version of ubuntu & also other distro. But got same error every time.

here is the link of the screenshot.
"http://s26.postimg.org/5ye6orptl/10443904_492797057533437_1603374469_n.jpg"

**System Config:**
AMD Phenom II x2 555 Black Edition
2GB DDR3 RAM
Gigabyte ga-ma74gmt-s2

please help me. I really want to use ubuntu again.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a hardware problem. Insure that your CPU is properly seated and that there are no bent pins. Insure that your version of the BIOS supports the CPU you have installed.

Start [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3268#dl) and choose the version of the mainboard that you have, then move to the support and downloads tab to download the list of supported CPU's and the BIOS version required. Followup by downloading the appropriate BIOS version to support your CPU and applying it in accordance with manufacturers instructions.

Source: Personal Experience